# Motion recovery from Optical flow information

Tags: c++, opencv, math, opticalflow

I have implemented a function that computes dense optical flow using OpenCV's `calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` between two consecutive frames. I'm writing the results to a `txt-file` in the form of `x,y` (one row per vector). The image sizes are `640x480` and I therefore have a `307200` vectors representing the the direction of velocity for each pixel in the image between two consecutive frames.

I'm wondering if it is possible to calculate a transformation matrix based on the information from Optical Flow. Will say, is it possible to reconstruct how the object in the image has moved between the two frames and reconstruct a transformation matrix so that I can align the second image to the first one?

The images contain nothing else then the object I want to track (Object build up by single points on white background) but the object itself is a projection of a rich scene thus there is some noise in Optical Flow information. The framerate `tf` between the images is known. Note that despite the fact that Optical Flow gives only 2D information (as the input images are 2D), the transformation matrix should later perform a 3D spatial transformation on an 3D object. The 2D images I fed into the Optical Flow computation are specific 2D-'snapshots' of that object. Due to restricted degrees of freedom a reconstructed transformation matrix coming from the 2D Optical Flow should be sufficient to correctly transform the 3D object.

I would like to use as much build-in OpenCV functionality as possible. I've read about [cv::EstimateRegitTransformation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) and [here](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2208) which I think could be helpful. But I'm not sure how to fed all the information the 307.200 vectors are holding properly into the computation pipeline for such a matrix. Maybe I could calculate a single vector that represents the average of the full Optical flow vector field and use its properties as input for motion recovery?

Comment: It's possible up to scale.  It could be a large object far away, or a small object near.  The motion also scales accordingly.   You need to provide size information about your object before you can estimate its full motion.

Comment: what you are looking for are so called structure from motion, and SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping)